# Can't get a list of shops with beautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code which should give me a list of shop's data. But the list is empty and doesn't show any errors...Any ideas how to do it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

def get_page_data(number):
    print('number:', number)

    url = 'https://www.brw.pl/siec-sprzedazy/?page={}'.format(number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    container = soup.find(class_='lista-salonow')
    items = container.find_all(class_='salon-kontener')


    dane = []

    for item in items:
        adres = item.find(class_='salon-szczegoly-adres').get_text(strip=True)
        dane.append([adres])

    return dane


wszystkie_dane = []
for number in range(1, 3):
    dane_na_stronie = get_page_data(number)

    wszystkie_dane.extend(dane_na_stronie)

dane = pd.DataFrame(wszystkie_dane, columns=['adres'])
dane.to_csv('brw.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What does the HTML code of the page you are trying to scrape look like?

Comment: I can't send a screenshot here ... Could you open [link](https://www.brw.pl/siec-sprzedazy/?page={}) to the site and check it on your own?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) which is clean, reliable and less code is needed to fetch the desired result straight from the provided website.

1. First i have fetched the API URL(ajax call) from the website after inspecting the network section of Chrome.
2. Doing a GET requests to fetch the data from API call.
3. Converting it in to JSON.
4. Finally looping over the contents.

> You can hit the URL in browser to see what all columns are coming in result and then you can use them as per your requirement. Right now i'm fetching only 5 in the print statement the same way you can fetch other columns as well.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def scrap_shops_data():
    api_url = 'https://www.brw.pl/ajax/zpLIv5maeKSYy8KP07immqanj-PVnJO6mQ/' #API URL to fetch data in JSON form

    shops_result = requests.get(api_url,verify=False).json() #Get request to fetch the data from the supplied URL
    for shop in shops_result: #loop to iterate on the JSON object
        print('-' * 100)
        print(shop['nazwa_salonu'])
        print(shop['adres'])
        print(shop['kod_pocztowy'])
        print(shop['miejscowosc'])
        print(shop['email'])
        print('-' * 100)

scrap_shops_data()
```